# Usage of function Split() in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, function, split

I have to write a program which clear all unneeded Spaces (" ") in string.

Example :
`John      Adamson  George`
//and show it as
`John Adamson George`

I found the function Split, but I cant figure out how does it works. Will be very thankful if someone help me.

*More about the task

You have 2 textbox-es in the first you input three names (no matter are they Upper or Lower case) and in the second they must be outputted with first letter- Capital letter and with 1 space between each 2 words.

`txtB.Text = Trim(A)`

`txtB.Text = Str(Split(Str(ArrA), " "))`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxaf4.jpg

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10811/147640

Comment: You should also provide your efforts what you've tried so far. This site is for helping others, not **working** for others

Comment: txtB.Text = Trim(A)
        txtB.Text = Str(Split(Str(ArrA), " "))

http://imgur.com/sKUMPwd

Comment: Thats the piece of code for which i need help, the rest is done. I needed just someone to tell me how to use String despite plain text in the function. Nothing more. I didn't requested someone to do it or I didn't even told that its homework, i'm doing exercieses on my own and need help to understand this one..

Comment: See [StringSplitOptions Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: `I cant figure out how does it works` [these guys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) know a thing or two about VB functions and how they work.  help yourself

Answer (score 0):

Split function will split the complete string into multiple words in an array [refer MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx), which you cannot assign directly to a textbox.

Based on the condition ***outputted with first letter- Capital letter and with 1 space between each 2 words*** , it looks like you need to:

- iterate over all the characters one by one (use **String.Substring()** function)
- then identify if the character is first character of the word (you can use flags to check if space has occurred in between), if yes, capitalize it using **String.ToUpper()** function
- check if there is a space (you can use flags to check if space has occurred in between) and ignore extra spaces
- Concatenate this into new string variable, and at the end assign it to TextBox B